# Hubot display url as link in Slack

Tags: slack-api, hubot

I'm using hubot with the hubot-slack adapter.

I have a very long url that I'd like to write to the chatroom, and would like to display it as a link.

**From this:**
http://magnum-ci.oak.domain.com:8080/job/nick_test_success_build/44/console

**To this:**
Click [here](http://magnum-ci.oak.domain.com:8080/job/nick_test_success_build/44/console) to view the console out

**I'm using:**
res.send "http://magnum-ci.oak.domain.com:8080/job/nick_test_success_build/44/console|link"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mshish is right, `<http://mylink.com|Show this>` should be the way to go.
You can test the output of your link using the [Message Builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting/builder).
Unfortunately it looks like this is not currently supported by the hubot.

https://github.com/slackhq/hubot-slack/issues/114

Comment: according to the github discussion link it looks like Slack developers are finally addressing the issue.  Hopefully their is a fix soon!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this recently with Hubot, but note that it doesn't work as a user.

Slack's docs make it look like you can use "labels" to display friendly URL names. See the last example on this page https://api.slack.com/docs/unfurling

You may be able to send the text

```
<http://mylink.com|Show this>
```

in a message and get the desired results.

I tried this a long time ago and don't remember if it worked.